# Python using child class's class attribute as default parameter without overriding method

Tags: python, oop, overriding, class-attributes

While initializing a class, the default arg for a parameter is a constant class attribute.

```py
class SomeClass:
    """Some class."""

    DEFAULT_VAL = 0

    def __init__(self, some_param: int = DEFAULT_VAL):
        print(f"default = {self.DEFAULT_VAL} and some_param = {some_param}.")


some_class = SomeClass()
```

Prints: `default = 0 and some_param = 0.`

When I subclass the class, and override the constant class attribute, it doesn't use it as the default parameter.

```py
class SomeChildClass(SomeClass):
    """Some child class."""

    DEFAULT_VAL = 1


some_child_class = SomeChildClass()
```

Prints: `default = 1 and some_param = 0.`

**Is there some way I can make this work, without explicitly overriding `__init__` in the child class?**

---

**Research**

[How to call parent class init with default values from child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393960/how-to-call-parent-class-init-with-default-values-from-child-class)

Question is very similar, yet they override `__init__`.

[Reinitialize parent class attributes during child class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783775/reinitialize-parent-class-attributes-during-child-class-definition)

Presents a possible solution using a `metaclass` to specify `DEFAULT_VAL` via `__new__`. This solution adds verbosity to `SomeClass`, which is not half bad.  I am wondering if it can be done even simpler though.

[Overriding class variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763743/overriding-class-variables-in-python)

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4763800/11163122), it informs me the problem is that `DEFAULT_VAL` is evaluated when the function `__init__` is defined.  However, I am not quite sure if using a `classmethod` is applicable in my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that *default values* take *objects, not variables/attributes*. The object is evaluated *once* when the function is defined. The generic way to solve this *in any function* is to do something like:

```
class SomeClass:
    """Some class."""

    DEFAULT_VAL = 0

    def __init__(self, some_param: int = None):
        if some_param is None:
            some_param = self.DEFAULT_VAL
        print(f"default = {self.DEFAULT_VAL} and some_param = {some_param}.")
```